# Android - Constantly changing text implementation advice needed

Tags: android-asynctask, textview, android, android-handler

I have a `TextView` which shows the amount of points the user has. Users points are filled with time to their max. I want my `TextView` every 20 sec. to display the time left for the point to be fully filled. (e.g. if the `TextView` shows "you have 500 points" I want it after 20 sec to change to "will be fully filled in 4:17 min", this text to be displayed for 10 sec. and then change back).
I thought of two ways to do this : 
1) With a `Handler` and `Runnable`, and each time the text changes to add another runnable task.
2) To do the points filling with `AsyncTask`, and the text will be changed with the `onProgressUpdate` method. 
3) Any other way you suggest (and think is better). 
Thanks for your help in advance,
Dan